Unbiased estimator of covariance^2
Assuming that the sample covariance $c_{ij}$ is an unbiased estimator of the true covariance $p_{ij}$, how do we find an unbiased estimator $\Theta$ which follows $\mathbb{E}(\Theta)=p_{ij}^2$?
I made an attempt assuming that $p_{ij}^2 = \mathbb{E}\left[ c_{ij}^2-{\rm Var}(c_{ij})\right]$. And from the Wishart distribution approximating
$${\rm Var}(c_{ij}) \approx \frac{1}{N-1}({\rm Var}(c_i){\rm Var}(c_j)+c_{ij}^2)$$

Such an estimator would depend on your distributional assumptions for the data--different distributional families would lead to different estimators (if any exist at all). What are those assumptions?

Initially I'm seeking without specify any distribution. However, I think the problem can be approximated by a Gaussian one.
